# Get all rows changed this week based on timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

How could I get all rows whom timestamp field was changed in current week using SQL query?

*Aditional info:
I already have timestamp field in each row.*

Comment: You can use an additional field to store modification timestamp.

Comment: I have timestamp field. What I am asking is how to retrieve all rows which had timestamp changed in the last week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may be over simplifying the issue, but from what I gather you need something like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    yourTable
WHERE   WEEK(TimestampField) = WEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
AND     YEAR(TimestampField) = YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to do the following

SELECT  * FROM    yourTable
   WHERE   DAY(TimestampField) >= DAY(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)-7